# laravel Parse error on view

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ')' on my view file. This is my controller:

```
public function gclogs()
    {
      $gclogs = DB::table('duplicategcs')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(20);
        return view('admin.gclogs')->with('gclogs',$gclogs);

    }
```

and this is just a snippet from view:

```
@foreach($gclogs as $gclog)
                            <tr>
                              <td>
                                {{gclog->id}}
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                {{gclog->user_id}}
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                {{gclog->google_id}}
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                {{gclog->google_email}}
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                {{gclog->created_at}}
                              </td>
                              <td>
                                <a href="{{url('admin/users/')}}/{{gclog->user_id}}">User Edit</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>

                            @endforeach
                              </tbody>
                            </table>
                            <div align="center">
                              {{ $gclogs->render() }}
                            </div>
```

Comment: You forgot a lot of dollar-signs there..

Comment: ohhhh ! Yeah you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget use `$` inside foreach.

Try this:

```
@foreach($gclogs as $gclog)
<tr>
  <td>
    {{$gclog->id}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{$gclog->user_id}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{$gclog->google_id}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{$gclog->google_email}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{$gclog->created_at}}
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="{{url('admin/users/')}}/{{$gclog->user_id}}">User Edit</a>
  </td>
</tr>

@endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
<div align="center">
  {{ $gclogs->render() }}
</div>
```